# How to add padding to each dynamically added sibling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to make a hierarchical system as

```
list
   item1
      item2
         item3
```

My HTML is as follows :

```
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
     <span class="third">Hello World</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
     <span class="third">Hello World2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
     <span class="third">Hello World3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I edit my CSS to give a padding to everytime a `second` div is added dynamically (using Javascript).

My CSS is :

```
.first{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.second{
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

[Link](http://codepen.io/ajaygaur319/pen/MeaoLq) to Code
I can edit the html and CSS entirely. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Comment: @phreakv6 No, I added a comment there.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Please clarify with an example that actually lines up with your sample code what output is desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `padding:10px;` to your .second css class.

```
.second{
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  padding:10px; 
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

If you want a hierarchy, you might want to change your html to something like this

```
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
     <span class="third">Hello World</span>
      <div class="second">
        <span class="third">Hello World2</span>
          <div class="second">
          <span class="third">Hello World3</span>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then add

```
.second{
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

Notice the `margin-left:20px;`.

Comment: but it will move each child and I have to make a hierarchy as I asked in the question. however I can edit the html and CSS entirely

Answer (score 0):

Try this code once may help for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var l = $('.second').length;
for(var i=0; i<=l;i++){
     .second:nth-child(i).css('padding',i+10);
  i = i+10;
 }
});
```

Comment: No, It didn't help me. It will give same padding to each second child but I want padding to increase every time a child is added.

Comment: then u better to add with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery you can add the code below which will add padding for each div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("div").each(function(index, item){
            $(item).css('padding-left', (index * 10 )  + "px");    
        });
    });
```